# Plotting Quarterly Data - Plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, data-science, plotly-python

I am trying to plot the below line chart in plotly, but my x axis is a quarter such as

```
df['quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.date, freq='Q')
quarter
2017Q1
2017Q2
...

fig = px.line(qtrly_comp, x="quarter", y="counts",template=template_style,markers = True)


fig.show()
```

I am getting error that reads - **TypeError: Object of type Period is not JSON` serializable**

datatype of the column is `period[Q-DEC]`

Is there anyway I can get plotly to read the x axis ? Thanks!

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options to overcome this problem either `to_timestamp()` or `.strftime('%m-%Y')`:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'Quarter':['2021Q1','2021Q2','2021Q3','2021Q4','2022Q1','2022Q2'],
                   'Values':[2,4,1,5,8,1]})

df['date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Quarter'], freq='Q').strftime('%m-%Y')

df = df.sort_values(by='Quarter', ascending=True)

fig = px.line(df, x='date', y='Values')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I would also add `fig.update_layout(xaxis = dict(tickmode = 'array', tickvals = df['date'], ticktext = df['Quarter']))`

Comment: More robust could be to do ```df['date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Quarter'], freq='Q').strftime('%Y-%m')```

and then 

```df = df.sort_values(by='Quarter', ascending=True)```